# Get logcats in android studio when device is in charge only mode

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I'm working on camera application and need to store picture in memory. I'm using android studio. When i connect my device with android studio through usb cable, my sd card not show in my phone, gallery images are not showing there. And unable to create file there. So I run application from android studio then set it on charge only mode and then sd card showing in my mobile and I'm able to create file but due to some error my application crashed. Problem is that I can't see the logs because I set it on charge only mode.

If I not set on charge only mode I'm not able to create file and access sd card.
If I set on charge only mode I'm not able to see logs in android studio.

Can you please let me know what I do.
If one the problem is fixed it's fine. Show sd card on usb debugging mode or show logs in charge mode.

Is it possible if yes then how ?

**Update**

I'm using external memory it automatically use sd card.

My major problem is to get logs. is there any way I can save logs and get these when connecting again with usb debugging. or something else

Comment: Then you have an old device with an early Android version. But why would you test your app with writing to an sd card? Just write to normal external memory. You could also remove the micro SD card. Without a micro SD card you should be able to test your app too. With logs.

Comment: I'm using external memory. it automatically use sd card. If it connect with  usb debugging I'm not able to create any file.

Comment: @greenapps my major problem is to get logs. is there any way I can save logs and get these when connecting again with usb debugging. or something else

Comment: All you say makes no sense. And you did not even react on old model and old version. Remove the micro SD card. Then you cannot have that problem.